Can i delete mono.android from my xamarin.ios project?
in visual studio 2022 using xamarin i have a .sln (3 projects: my backend project, myapp.android, myapp.ios) when i build my ios app in release mode, in my folder release, i can find mono.android and some other files refer to android. can i disable mono.anrdoid in my xamarin.ios project?
I searched a lot on the web, but I didn't quite understand how to exclude mono.android from my ios project
is it right to have mono.android in the release folder of the ios project?
in release folder i don't want files refer to my android project.

The entire Xamarin stack has been deprecated, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin so you should migrate now.

Mono.Android is the reference that gives you all the native Android references in your project, this should never be referenced from an iOS project, if you do see such a reference you should remove it, to remove it go to your Dependencies and remove Mono.Android from your iOS project.
In your project references in the iOS project remove Mono.Android, (The screenshot is from an Android project hence you don't see Xamarin.iOS here)


in this dir i haven't any mono.android link

Can you share a SS of what you do see then?

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/8705/G99ak6.png

if this is all then you don't have a reference to mono android in your iOS project, you might have it in your Cross-Platform project check there

yes, i have mono.android in the Cross-Platform project, i tried to excude mono.android from reference but i have a lot of reference to the dll in my code then i have a lot of error, do you have any suggestions?

Why do you think your cross platform code uses native library? You should be fixing this by doing it that right way!
